# Is this null user the result of a null value?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

Consider this Stack Overflow question:

*[How to use #include directive correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464560/how-to-use-include-directive-correctly)*

The accepted answer is by the null user. Is this common?

Comment: When questions are migrated from one site to another, if the asker/answerer doesn't have an account on the new site, their name appears greyed out like that. This doesn't appear to be a migration, but it's possible the answerer's username actually was "null", and something similar happened (deleted account, maybe?).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) :)

Comment: @gnat you sometimes come up with the craziest duplicates (that are usually right), this is the best one yet.

Comment: Confirmed in database; originating user's display name

Comment: @psubsee2003 then, you probably gotta like [this dupe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247362/i-am-looking-for-an-existing-mutation-generator-for-java-file#comment810671_247362) too :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Grayed out users like your example appear when the post owner does not have an account.  This happens in 3 cases:

- Migrated question from a site where the user does have an account to where the user does not have one
- The account was deleted.
- The post owner requested that the content be disassociated from their account.  As such, it is treated similar to a post with a deleted OP.

When migrating, the user name is not anonymized so you will see the display name from the original site.  When deleted , the display name is automatically anonymized prior to deletion, so it would be replaced by `userXXXXXX` (where XXXXXX is the former user id number for the user).  I can't actually recall exactly how a disassociated post is anonymized but it does not make sense to use the specific user id.

However, in the early days, user names were not automatically anonymized prior to the account deletion and the name that was left on the content was the last display name the user used.  That is most likely what happened here as the question in question was not migrated from another site.  A user with the name `null` answered that question and then later deleted his/her account.

My understanding is users did sometimes manually anonymized their account before deletion, [as recommended by Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26844/there-needs-to-be-a-way-to-delete-content-or-disassociate-your-account-from-said/26853#26853), so they could have manually changed their name to `null` first then requested deletion of the account in order to disassociate themselves from the content after the account was deleted.

To address your specific question, "null" isn't anything specific, just what the user's name was at the time of account deletion.  It could have been changed to anything.  But content with deleted owners is quite common.  My SQL and knowledge of the fields in the data dump are not up to the task, but I believe you can find a good idea in a [Data Explorer Query](http://data.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I think that if a user requests that some/all posts are disassociated from the account (not necessarily account deletion) the name also stays the same. But I don't know this for sure.

Comment: @ArtjomB. very valid point - I think you may be correct on that.  Let me see if I can confirm it

Comment: @ArtjomB. disassociated posts [apparently get anonymized](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131665/what-exactly-happens-when-i-ask-to-delete-my-account/131666#comment363403_131666) as well, at least according to Will (aka Won't), who is a former mod if you weren't aware of that

Comment: "anonymized [...] replaced by userXXXXXX (where XXXXXX is the former user id number for the user)" interesting definition of "anonymized".

Comment: @CodesInChaos and do you know anyone's user id that it would be identifiable?

Comment: @CodesInChaos however for disassociation, you are right, that doesn't make sense.  I tweaked the post and now I am going to try to figure it out.